# Multidimentional array row show as column date wise using mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, date, foreach

I Have this MySQL table:

```
+------------+-------+---------------+
| date       | event | name          |
+------------+-------+---------------+
| 2014-08-22 |     3 | A             |
| 2014-08-22 |     3 | B             |
| 2014-08-26 |    11 | A             |
| 2014-08-26 |    15 | B             |
| 2014-08-27 |     1 | A             |
| 2014-08-27 |     1 | B             |
| 2014-09-10 |     2 | A             |
| 2014-09-10 |     2 | B             |
+------------+-------+---------------+
```

I want to display above data shown as below:

```
+------------+-------+---------------+
| date       | A     | B             |
+------------+-------+---------------+
| 2014-08-22 |     3 | 3             |
| 2014-08-26 |    11 | 15            |
| 2014-08-27 |     1 | 1             |
| 2014-09-10 |     2 | 2             |
+------------+-------+---------------+
```

Please, help me how we can get the format

Comment: You've tagged this with PHP, so just handle the display logic in the application level code (e.g. a simple loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I created your table and called it `tester`:

```
mysql> select * from tester;
+------------+-------+------+
| date       | event | name |
+------------+-------+------+
| 2014-08-22 |     3 | A    |
| 2014-08-22 |     3 | B    |
| 2014-08-26 |    11 | A    |
| 2014-08-26 |    15 | B    |
| 2014-08-27 |     1 | A    |
| 2014-08-27 |     1 | B    |
| 2014-09-10 |     2 | A    |
| 2014-09-10 |     2 | B    |
+------------+-------+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My idea is simple:

- I create a view where I save only the A values and their corresponding dates.
- I create a second view where I save only the B values and their corresponding dates
- I join these views on their dates.

Here are the full steps with their demo:

```
mysql> create view theAs as (select date, event AS A from tester where name='A'); 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.30 sec)

mysql> select * from theAs;
+------------+------+
| date       | A    |
+------------+------+
| 2014-08-22 |    3 |
| 2014-08-26 |   11 |
| 2014-08-27 |    1 |
| 2014-09-10 |    2 |
+------------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create view theBs as (select date, event AS B from tester where name='B'); 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.30 sec)

mysql> select * from theBs;
+------------+------+
| date       | B    |
+------------+------+
| 2014-08-22 |    3 |
| 2014-08-26 |   15 |
| 2014-08-27 |    1 |
| 2014-09-10 |    2 |
+------------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select theAs.date, theAs.A, theBs.B from theAs join theBs on theAs.date=theBs.date;
+------------+------+------+
| date       | A    | B    |
+------------+------+------+
| 2014-08-22 |    3 |    3 |
| 2014-08-26 |   11 |   15 |
| 2014-08-27 |    1 |    1 |
| 2014-09-10 |    2 |    2 |
+------------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Begueradj